# Python - Using GridSearchCV with NLTK

Tags: performance, scikit-learn, nltk, random-forest, hyperparameters

I'm a little unsure as to how I can apply SKLearn's GridSearchCV to a random forest I'm using with NLTK. How to use GridSearchCV normally is discussed [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), however my data is formatted differently to the standard x and y split. Here is my code:

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC


reader_train = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('C:/Users/User/Documents/Sentiment/machine_learning/amazon/amazon/', r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(\w+)/*', encoding='latin1')

documents_train = [ (list(reader_train.words(fileid)), category)
                 for category in reader_train.categories()
                 for fileid in reader_train.fileids(category) ]

all_words = []

for w in reader_train.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3500]

def find_features(documents):
    words = set(documents)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

return features

featuresets_train = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents_train]

np.random.shuffle(featuresets_train)

training_set = featuresets_train[:1600]
testing_set = featuresets_train[:400]

RandFor = SklearnClassifier(RandomForestClassifier())
RandFor.train(training_set)
print("RandFor accuracy:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(RandFor, testing_set)) *100)
```

This code, instead of producing a conventional x and y split, produces a list of tuples, where each tuple is in the following format:

```
({'i': True, 'am': False, 'conflicted': False ... 'about': False}, neg)
```

Is there a way to apply GridSearchCV to data in this format?

Comment: You are wrapping already perfect scikit learn estimator (`RandomForestClassifier` in this case) to a nltk compatible one. Do you need to work with `RandomForestClassifier` and `GridSearchCV`?

Comment: GridSearchCV is not a necessity, I'd be happy to try other optimization algorithms. It does need to be RandomForest however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the `training_set` to a scikit-usable form, you just need to do

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vectorizer = DictVectorizer()

X_train, y_train = list(zip(*training_set))
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)

X_test, y_test = list(zip(*testing_set))
X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test)
```

After that you can easily call

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print("RandFor accuracy:", (accuracy) * 100)
```

Comment: Thankyou mate, very appreciated, and seems to be working very well! Have a good day.